# How to pass 2 variables using json dumps to an ajax function?

Tags: ajax, django, django-views

I want to pass two variable: *scenario_name* and *scenario_id* from my view to my ajax function in the html code.

So basically in the database, each Organization can have multiple scenarios. The organization and scenario models have 2 fields each: an id field and a name field.

And my other doubt is, once I pass it to ajax, how do I access the variables passed?

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from Organization.models import Organization
from django.http import HttpResponse
from Scenario.models import Scenario
import json
from django.core import serializers


def alertindex(request):
return render(request, 'alertindex.html', {
    'Organization': Organization.objects.all(),
    })
def get_scenario(request):
    org_id = request.GET.get('org_id')
    organization = Organization.objects.get(pk=int(org_id))
    scenario = organization.scenario_set.all()
    scenarios = serializers.serialize("json", scenario)
    return scenarios
```

urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url


urlpatterns = [
    # Add alert url
    url(r'^$', views.alertindex, name='alertindex'),
    # Bind data in scenario drop down
    url(r'^/Scenario$', views.get_scenario,   name='Get_Scenario'),
```

]

my ajax function

```
       var orgID = $(this).val();
        var scenarios = '{{ scenarios }}'
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{% url 'Get_Scenario' %}",
            data: { org_id: orgID},
                success: function () {
                var udata = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < scenarios.length; i++) {
                    udata = udata + "<option value='"+ scenarios[i].scenario_id + "'>" + scenarios[i].scenario_name + "</option>"
                $("#txtScenario").append(udata);
            }
    },
});
```

The url Get_Scenario links me to my view having the function get_scenario.

The error that I am facing is " str' object has no attribute 'get' "

Traceback:

File "/Users/anirudhchakravarthy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/anirudhchakravarthy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 97, in **call**
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/Users/anirudhchakravarthy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: didn't you solved your problem? :(  just upload your full view please

Comment: you just can pass it to context data, then use all serialized data in template.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm facing a repititive error. Just updated the question as I forgot to mention the error

Comment: ok then please upload your full view

Comment: Did that. I also added the traceback if you might need it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `JsonResponse`. Here's sample code.

(It's better to check try/exception and send 404 when not found object)

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_scenario(request):
    org_id = request.GET.get('org_id')
    # you can do your own validation
    try:
        organization = Organization.objects.get(pk=int(org_id))
        scenario = organization.scenario_set.all()
        scenarios = serializers.serialize("json", scenario)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        data = {
            'result': 'fail',
        }
        return JsonResponse(status=404, data)

    data = {
        "scenarios": scenarios,
        # add more data you want
    }

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

For more information about `JsonResponse`, just check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

Comment: Thanks for that! One small question, where is the django context being used here?

Comment: This view not using django context. You just send json data by `JsonResponse`, so you don't have to render context data. In `alertindex`, the `render` function will use django context.

Comment: One more thing, the error is now gone and data is being passed. But I'm not able to access the options in the ajax function. Could you just finally help me out with that?

Comment: What do you mean not able to access options?

Comment: In the options tag in the ajax function, the data isn't being received.

Comment: Oh you missed `response.data`. You have to pass the data to success function. like this `success: function (response)` and use it by `var your_data = response.data;`

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it's giving me an error saying unresolved variable data

Comment: Never mind it's fully functional now. Thanks a lot for your assistance!